# Where is color property defined when creating a custom theme for Material-UI

Tags: material-ui

I am following the example here [1] to create a custom theme using Material-UI. On Line 10 in `App.js` [2] it references `color="textSecondary"`, can someone explain where the value `textSecondary` comes from?

I was able to get the example to work using:
`style={{ color: theme.palette.secondary.light }}`
but I'd prefer to be able to use the shorter syntax reference.

Full `App.js` code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import ProTip from './ProTip';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

import theme from './theme';

function MadeWithLove() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" style={{ color: theme.palette.secondary.light }} align="center">
      {'Built with love by the '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        Material-UI
      </Link>
      {' team.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm">
      <Box my={4}>
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h1" gutterBottom>
          Create React App v4-beta example
        </Typography>
        <ProTip />
        <MadeWithLove />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

My `theme.js` file is:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#6fbf73',
      main: '#4caf50',
      dark: '#357a38',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#5464c0',
      main: '#2a3eb1',
      dark: '#1d2b7b',
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

[1] https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/create-react-app

[2] https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/create-react-app/src/App.js#L10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [documentation for `Typography` component](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/#props), you can provide several options for the `color` prop:

```
name: color
type: enum: 'initial', 'inherit', 'primary', 'secondary', 'textPrimary', 'textSecondary', 'error'
default: 'initial'
description: The color of the component. It supports those theme colors that make sense for this component.
```

`textSecondary` is defined here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Typography/Typography.js#L92 as

`theme.palette.text.secondary`

Comment: Great! And now I see why textSecondaryLight doesn't do anything.